# Ajustar campos de un formulario Toolset en una línea

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando un formulario de búsqueda personalizado en `WordPress` con la herramienta de `toolset`, para poder segmentar búsquedas en portfolios, entradas, etc.

El HTML de la zona que estoy tratando es este:

```html
[wpv-filter-start hide="false"]
[wpv-filter-controls]
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wpv-post-search">[wpml-string context="wpv-views"]Buscar en Crearte[/wpml-string]</label>
    [wpv-filter-search-box placeholder="Introduce algo para buscar..." output="bootstrap"]
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="form-group">
    <label for="wpv-portfolio_category"></label>
    [wpv-control-post-taxonomy taxonomy="portfolio_category" type="select" default_label="Categoría" url_param="wpv-portfolio_category"]
</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="form-group">
    <label for="wpv-post_tag"></label>
    [wpv-control-post-taxonomy taxonomy="post_tag" type="select" default_label="Etiquetas" url_param="wpv-post_tag"]
</div><div class="col-sm-3">[wpv-filter-submit name="Buscar" output="bootstrap" class="btn-secondary"]</div></div>
</div>[/wpv-filter-controls]
[wpv-filter-end]
```

Ahora mismo se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, hasta el botón de Enviar se ve mal.

Me gustaría que quedase todo en la misma línea, de esta forma:

[Buscador]     [Categorías]     [Etiquetas]     [Enviar]

Answer (score -1):

Debes ponerlo todo en columnas. En la primera el buscador, en la segunda el desplegable de categorias, en la tercera el desplegable de etiquetas y en la última el botón enviar.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class = "form-group col-12 col-md-3">Buscador</div>
    <div class = "form-group col-12 col-md-3">Categorias</div>
    <div class = "form-group col-12 col-md-3">Etiquetas</div>
    <div class = "form-group col-12 col-md-3">Botón enviar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explicado. Gracias por tus comentarios.